# ListBox doesn't show changes to DataSource

Tags: data-binding, listbox, c#-2.0

I thought this was a simple problem, but I can't find any information on the web. I'm binding a ListBox to a `List` using `BindingSource` like so:

```
List<Customer> customers = MyMethodReturningList();

BindingSource customersBindingSource = new BindingSource();
customersBindingSource.DataSource = customers;

customersListBox.DataSource = customersBindingSource;
```

Now, when I add or delete from `customers` list, my `ListBox` gets updated (even without using `ResetBindings` on `BindingSource`), but if I change any of the customer objects in the list, it does not. Calling `ResetBindings` has no effect. I even implemented my own `BindingList`, but the behaviour hasn't changed.
The `Customer` class uses properties for accessing and modification of data. Its `ToString()` content is displayed in the list.

I'm using C# in .Net 2.0.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you use a `BindingList` you don't even need the `BindingSource`:

```
BindingList<Customer> customers = new BindingList<Customer>(MyMethodReturningList());
customersListBox.DataSource = customers;
```

Answer (score 4):

OK, here's a dirty fix: wenever you need to refresh the box contents set datasource = null, then rebind it.

the reason it doesn't update is because the objects in the list haven't changed and it only checks the refrences of the object rather than their contents.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's what I did in the end (I haven't got the code right now), but as you said, it's dirty.

Comment: Another problem is, datasource loses its design time settings e.g. DisplayMember and ValueMember properties gets unset.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a bug in the list box which can cause this problem. If you set the SelectionMode to **None** this problem appears.

As a work around I set the selection mode to One and then back to None when updating the datasource.

Comment: Many people say to use ItemsControl but your suggestion is the best. By the way I wonder why Microsoft doesn't fix this for almost 10 years?

Answer (score 0):

I got around this problem by converting data to array when updating source. Please see UpdateData method. This way you can update your combo box without losing ComboBox Settings.

```
class Person {
   public int Id {get; set; }
   public string FirstName{ get; set; }
   public string SurName {get; set; }
}

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "FirstName";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
    comboBox1.DataSource = m_PersonList;
}

public void UpdateData() {
    m_PersonList[0].FirstName = "Firstname1";
    comboBox1.DataSource = m_PersonList.ToArray<Person>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this question was asked almost 6 years ago but other than work-arounds I do not see a correct answer here.
When you change property of an item in a collection the event gets raised for the element (object) but not the collection. So the collection does not see a change and will not refresh bound controls. Elements inside all binding collections and most generic collections like `List<>` receive 2 events, `PropertyChanging` and `PropertyChanged`. When a property of the element inside collection is changed, the event gets triggered. All you need to do is add an event handler that would trigger either re-binding or raise an event on the `Collection`.