# ListBox Items Disappear

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, .net-1.1

I currently have a ListBox (called wafersListBox) bounded to an ArrayList of a certain object type (called wafers). When I want to add to the ListBox dynamically, I use the following code:

```
wafersListBox.DataSource = null;
wafersListBox.DataSource = wafers;
wafersListBox.Refresh();
```

This successfully changes the items in the ListBox, but all of the items disappear (they're still there and can be selected, but the user just can't see them).

Any ideas on how to fix this?

UPDATE:
This is my Wafer class:

```
public class Wafer
{
    public string maID;

    public string MID
    {
        get
        {
            return maID;
        }
        set
        {
            maID = value;
        }
    }

    public Wafer(string m)
    {
        maID = m;
    }
}
```

This is the code that I call, it adds a copy of the currently selected item to the listbox:

```
Wafer w = wafersListBox.SelectedItem as Wafer;
wafers.Add(w);          

wafersListBox.DataSource = null;
wafersListBox.DisplayMember = "MID";
wafersListBox.DataSource = wafers;
wafersListBox.Refresh();
```

Comment: Any info on the elements in your `ArrayList`?

Comment: I don't see any code initializing your `wafers`?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably tell the `wafersListBox` what property to use as it's caption.

Do it like this;

```
wafersListBox.DisplayMember = "PropertyNameThatYouWantToShow";
```

Comment: Thank you, but I've tried this and it still does the same thing

Comment: Could you please show what you did? Also it would help to see the code of the object you are trying to show. Could you please update your question with this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - I'm not able to add an additional comment, which would have been preferable over writing a new "answer" but do you see any difference if you switch the position of the lines as below?

```
    Wafer w = wafersListBox.SelectedItem as Wafer;
    wafers.Add(w);          

    wafersListBox.DataSource = null;
    wafersListBox.DataSource = wafers;
    wafersListBox.DisplayMember = "MID";
    wafersListBox.Refresh();
```

One other thing I just came across on a different SO posting ([ListBox doesn't show changes to DataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609544/listbox-doesnt-show-changes-to-datasource)):

"There is also a bug in the list box which can cause this problem. If you set the SelectionMode to None this problem appears.

As a work around I set the selection mode to One and then back to None when updating the datasource."